# question on c compilation

Tags: c, linux, compiler-construction

On a linux box

is it compulsory to write a program into a file and compile it

cant this be done from command line

```
localhost$gcc "include<stdio.h> int main(){printf('hello world'); return o; }"
```

Comment: Please give a reason for the downvote

Comment: I didn't downvote, but what happened when you tried? Even if it is possible, running code from the command line is feasible only for scripting languages.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I can see why someone would. Your question indicates a certain lack of very basic understanding of the technologies and way of doing things. The question is weird, the sample code provided is meaningless and contains basic errors. No problem, we all have to start somewhere,  most of us start from a book. You might considerer reading a couple of chapters from http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/imprint_downloads/informit/perens/0130091154.pdf  or http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/writings/taoup/html/  to get a quick overview. Have fun and gain experience! See you around.

Comment: @peter:thanks..I am not new to c but had this question for a long time now..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sure you can, but i doubt that that makes sense....

```
$ echo '#include <stdio.h>
int main() { printf("hello world\n"); return 0; }' | gcc -x c -
$ ./a.out 
hello world
$
```

gcc options:

```
  -o <file>                Place the output into <file>
  -x <language>            Specify the language of the following input files
                           Permissible languages include: c c++ assembler none
                           'none' means revert to the default behavior of
                           guessing the language based on the file's extension
```

Comment: @ Markus:Can a.out be changed to a user choice instead,say test1.out for the above code..

Comment: @Rajeev Yes, specify the -o option, which tells gcc where it should write to.

e.g. gcc file.c -o example; ./example

Answer (score 0):

I always liked [Barry Browns answer to FizzBuzz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437/what-is-your-solution-to-the-fizzbuzz-problem/207068#207068):

In C:

```
F
```

Compile with:

```
gcc -DF='main(){int i;for(i=0;i<101;puts(i++%5?"":"Buzz"))printf(i%3?i%5?"%d":"":"Fizz",i);}' fizzbuzz.c
```